# Lenovo LS2223WC monitor low resolusion

Tags: lenovo, display-resolution, monitor

My fresh Ubuntu 22.04 installation is not OK with Lenovo LS2223WC monitor.
Its maximum available resolution is 1024x728.
While it happens higher resolutions with other monitors, I wonder if it is a problem with the monitor driver and installation of a supporting driver may be a fix.
The monitor is connected by standard RGB cable.
The monitor is not recognized by the OS.

```
lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
```

Update:
Although I have managed to solve the problem, but I have finally found out that the main problem was from the cable.

Comment: You have not said the video card and driver for a video question so no able to be much help.

Comment: The thing is that the same video card with the same driver is working well with other external monitors
That's why I did not mention the video card info
lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked the monitor with another Windows PC and it worked perfectly.
So I finally decided to go through the guidelines in the following link and a custom mode to the monitor:

https://www.tecmint.com/set-display-screen-resolution-in-ubuntu/

It now works OK.